# Not able to push my django project up on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, python-2.7

I have created a python2.7/django(1.4.1) Application, which I wanted to deploy on heroku

The project is already on git so I did the following.

1> create heroku --stack cedar

2> created requirement.txt : contains only 
    Django==1.4.1

3> create Procfile : contains 
    web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

4> git push heroku master

this throws the following error

```
Counting objects: 90, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 154.73 KiB, done.
Total 90 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:salty-tor-8958.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:salty-tor-8958.git'
```

I went through this previously asked SO Question : [Deploying existing Django app on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974902/deploying-existing-django-app-on-heroku)
where the talk is about the directory structure, and Django directory structure has changed since then, So what am I doing wrong?

Here my directory structure is like so:

```
   MyApp
     | 
   MyApp
     |-- __init__
     |-- settings.py
     |-- urls.py
   my_module
     |-- __init__
     |-- views.py
     |-- static
     |-- templates
   manage.py
   requirement.txt
   Procfile
```

I am working on Fedora, so had to use the rubygem to install herokutoolbelt

`Heroku Version : heroku-gem/2.33.5 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

Its `requirements.txt` not `requirement.txt`

Further read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django