# error in deploying django app to heroku from windows

Tags: django, git, deployment, heroku

typing the following command in the git-shell:

> (venv) path_to_project_directory> git push heroku master

gives the following error:

> Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.154' (RSA) to the list of known
> hosts.
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I checked the remote in the config file and through the (git remote -v) command --- but the remote appears to be correctly added :-

> (venv) path_to_project_directory> git remote -v
>
> heroku  git@heroku.com:something.git (fetch)
>
> heroku  git@heroku.com:something.git (push)
>
> origin  username@bitbucket.org/username/repo_name.git (fetch)
>
> origin  username@bitbucket.org/username/repo_name.git (push)

I also checked the SSH keys in the directory C:\Users\abc.ssh\ and through the (heroku keys) command :-

> (venv) path_to_project_directory> path_to_heroku\bin\heroku keys
>
> === myemail@email.com Keys
>
> ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxx== abc@abc-PC

this SSH key is the same as the one that appears on my Heroku account page...

so why is this error coming up when I am trying to push?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974902/deploying-existing-django-app-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off removing your key, generating a new one and adding it. Instructions from Heroku are [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku). Typically you want to use one key, and not a separate key for Heroku.

Your process would look like:

```
$ heroku keys:remove myemail@email.com
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
$ heroku keys:add
```